# How can one run multiple nUnit test fixtures in parallel but not run child combinatorial test method in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I have multiple test fixtures the utilizes both [TestFixture()] arguments as well [Combinatorial] on the inner test method.

```
namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture(Chrome)]
    [TestFixture(Firefox)]
    [TestFixture(Edge)]
    public class LoginFixture: BrowserSetupBase
    {
        public LoginFixture(string browser) : base(browser: browser){}

        [Test, Combinatorial]
        public void ShouldLoginAndLogout(
            [Values("SiteOne", "SiteTwo")] string website,
            [ValueSource(typeof(UserNamesClass), nameof(Values))] string userName
        )
        {
            // Run Test
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible, via the use of nUnit's `[Parallelizable()]` attribute, to be able to run separate fixture files in parallel but the tests within each fixture as `[NonParallelizable]`.

EDIT: Per @ascendantofrain's comment the three fixtures should run in parallel with other fixtures but not with one another. It's still not clear whether the test cases are intended to run in parallel or sequentially. I'll update my answer. @Charlie

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can simply add `[Parallelizable]` to your fixture. The tests will run sequentially within that fixture, but in parallel to the tests in all other fixtures.

If you want something different to happen, please add more detail.

UPDATE:
The original answer stands. That is, if you use `[Parallelizable]` on a fixture it runs in parallel. If you don't put `[Parallelizable]` on any tests, they run sequentially within the fixture.

Some clarifications and definitions:

1. I'm talking about the attribute without any arguments. Various `ParallelScope` args can change things, but not in any way that imapacts this question.
2. A `TestFixture` is represented by a C# class. With three `TestFixture` attributes, there are three fixtures.
3. `[Parallelizable]` applies to the class and all three fixtures get the same behavior with respect to parallelism.

NUnit runs fixtures either in parallel with others or by themselves. There are no features to say "run this in parallel but not at the same time as some other fixture. The three fixtures in this example form a sort of group, since they use the same class. It might have been possible to give `ParallelizableAttribute` some kind of argument that does exactly what you want, but unfortunately we didn't. :-( You could ask the current team to add the feature, of course.

There are two workarounds possible:

1. Just accept the current behavior and run these fixtures sequentially. If you haven't timed it running that way, you should not assume that the performance will be bad.
2. More difficult, but possible: Create some resource, e.g. a monitor, which each fixture tries to acquire before running. You could do it in a `OneTimeSetUp` method. Bear in mind that you will still be tying up three execution threads while these fixtures run, but they won't interfere with one another. There may already be an unprotected common resource, which is what motivates you to not want to run all three in parallel.

It's not clear whether you want test cases to run in parallel or sequentially *within the fixture*. They default to sequential unless you are using some global, assembly-level attribute to change the behavior -- not my favorite approach, btw. If you want them to run in parallel *within the fixture* add `[Parallelizable]` to each method or use `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]` on the fixtures.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this wasn't the solution. What currently happens is that no matter which ParallelScope value I use for the Parallelizable attribute, all of the TextFixture parameters will run in parallel with each other. 

I can't use ParallelScope.None because I still want this fixture to run in parallel with other fixture files, I just dont want this particular fixture to run in parallel with itself. I hope that helps clear it up.

Comment: I edited your question and now I'll edit my answer. FYI, you should never give new info in a comment because comments are sometimes cleaned up. We want the questions and answers to make sense for future users. If you do update the question, feel free to remove my edit in the process.